# Netbeans list only 91 plugins while plugins site has morethan 700, how to get all of them in the list so that they can be easily installed

Tags: plugins, netbeans

Netbeans list only 98 plugins while plugins site has morethan 700 how to get all of them in the list. I know they can be manually installed, but that doesnt make sense to me. i guess i have to add some repository but i cant find the web address for that even if I have google several times. How can I get all 700 plugins listed on the netbeans itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are about 700 plugins listed there.
but try filtering it according to your version.
your version will be 7.2 I think.
there are 52 Community Contributed Plugins. means verified for that version.
others are Certified Plugins.
all are already listed in netbeans plugin portal.

Comment: i guess I can install most of them by downloading manually.. but its tedious task. I wish I could do that from the plugin addition option from netbeans itself